# Creating an a project-site for an open source project

Tags: open-source, documentation, websites, project-hosting

So I have an open source project that I would like to promote and I want to create a project-site for it where I will host the documentation, etc. (preferably something that integrates with github for handling downloads, issues, etc). The project-site should be just like a typical.

Is there anything out-of-the-box for this or do I have to code it from scratch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use [GitHub](https://github.com/), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Because I need a page  where I can describe the project, where the user can browse the documentation, see a working example, etc.

Comment: Github and sourceforge are great for developers but the end users expect to see something more like a product page. If Mozilla was available of github and github only do you thing there would be this many people using it?

Comment: A lot of projects have a separate domain targeted at customers. Just combine one of them with a 'normal' product website.

Comment: @Raphael take a look at GitHub pages (example of what you can do: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've already coded a solution for this, but you may want to look at [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org). It allows you to have an integrated project page, wiki, bug tracking, and repository all in one. It'll even do zip files of the project for you, so people don't need fossil to download the source.

It will require you to have somewhere to host it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use one of the simple "out of the box" website solutions like Wordpress. They are trivial to set up, can look pretty sleek, and will allow you to spend as much time working on your actual project as possible. Combine that with something like Github or Sourceforge and you end up with a fairly robust solution.